# Transformation matrices affine vs. euclidean

Tags: terminology, definition

is there a difference between an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) an the euclidean transformation mentioned in [this tutorial](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1950-g/asgn/proj6/resources/ImageWarping.pdf)?

Is an affine transformation a type of euclidean transformation?

Comment: Please don't let us do all the reading, and reproduce the essential information in your post.

Comment: I have done all the reading and more for two days now and am still missing this basic understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the the "Euclidean warping" is a special type of affine transformation.

Affine transformations are very general. They are made up of a nonsingular linear transformation plus a translation. The author explicitly describes Euclidean warping as encompassing *scale, rotation and translation* only. In other words, he wants to carry out the geometry of Euclidean similarity.

Examples of affine transformations that are not Euclidean similarity transformations (as described in the paper):

1. Reflections
2. [Shear mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping)

Comment: Why then according to [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/affine-transformation.html) it seems as though the rotation transformation is incorporated into the euclidean transformation? does it have the same $\sin \cos$ components?